# How can I properly extend Spring Bean and acess the Child Class?

Tags: java, spring

I get a null pointer when I try to access a method in a Spring Bean child class, for example, in `class A` below:

```
new B().methodB();
```

How can I properly extend Spring Bean and acess the Child Class?

```
@Component
@Scope(proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS, value = "prototype")
class A {
    @Autowired
    protected Object objectl

    public void methodA() {
        new B().methodB();
    }

    public void doStuff() {
        System.out.println("Successfully called...");
    }
}

class B extends B {
    public void methodB() {
        objectl.doStuff();
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

The problem is that I'm trying to to create an Array Objcet of B, something like `B[] b = new B[size]`, but I can't figure how to from a Spring Bean.

Comment: Why do you think Spring would be involved in the expression `new B().methodB();`?

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: Like I said in the Update, the problem is that I'm trying to to create an Array Objcet of B, something like B[] b = new B[size], but I can't figure how to from a Spring Bean.

Comment: If you want Spring to be involved, you'll need to get the **beans** from a **bean context**, that is Spring's `ApplicationContext`. You can't be initializing them yourself.